# Subir archivos mediante curl

Tags: curl

estoy intentando enviar archivos mas los parametros mediante curl en la misma peticion

```
 curl -k -X POST -F 'image=@/ruta/123.jpg' -F "title=test&description=tesst" http://localhost:3000/upload
```

Pero me salta el siguiente error

> {"name":"MulterError","message":"Unexpected field","code":"LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE","field":"image","storageErrors":[]}

Gracias de antemano

Comment: [Ver aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31530200/5587982). Convendría que expliques mejor tu contexto y que pongas en la pregunta las etiquetas de las librerías o lenguajes de programación/tecnologías que estás usando.

Comment: @A.Cedano El stack con el que estoy trabajando es independiente a mi servicio web, solo estaba tratando de enviar imagenes y parametros mediante curl. Aun asi ya lo resolvi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para enviar imagenes mas parametros en una misma peticion tipo POST basta con utilizar la bandera `-F` de la siguiente manera

```
curl http://tu-pagina -F "nombre-del-parametro=@/ruta-de-la-imagen/" -F "otro-parametro=nuevo%20titulo"
```

Comment: Marca la respuesta como aceptada mediante un click en el check verde del costado :D